# Send app request to friend from page tab without pop up..!

Tags: facebook-graph-api, request, multi-friend-selector

Sound like tricky to me..

Sending app request in a popup is a common scenario..

I am trying it to be something static , NO POP UP, USERs should be visible just like any other media on page, with check boxes allowing selection with a send button.

MY guess is something like this.

1. I need to get the list of the friends and display it with check boxes.
2. After user selects some particular check boxes, and clicks the send button.
3. I need to get the list of the friends to generate the dialogue with those ids and send the request..

But even then, As far code is concerned, I am not able to achieve this, little hints would do i guess.

here is the example I want to achieve..
https://www.facebook.com/mittromney/app_159952444141722